# VBA excel find last fully drilled down PivotField

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, vba

i need to reference the Pivot-RowField that is below the last fully drilled down of PivotField of a Pivot table.
[image: Snapshot of example]

[External link to the image]
(http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160119/urgaltwn.png)!

In the Example it would be PivotField("Region") because the next level "Town" is not fully consolidated.

Sadly neither the property of the PivotField .ShowDetail nor .DrilledDown are helping me out, since they (I believe) are refering to the ranges in the .DataRange behind the field.

So far I tried looping through all the pivot items and check their .Showdetail property but they are all set to `True` even though the streets in region East e.g. are not shown.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

regs
Tim

Code attempt:

```
Private Function pivotRowField(pvt As PivotTable) As PivotField
Dim pI As PivotItem, ok, test As Boolean

   'determine last fully consolidated pivotRowField

    For i = pvt.PivotFields.Count To 1 Step -1
    ok = false
    test = False
    'test = pvt.PivotFields(i).DataRange.Cells(1).ShowDetail <- true for all
'test = pvt.RowFields(i).ShowDetails <- not possible

    With pvt.RowFields(i)

    For Each pvitem In .PivotItems
        On Error Resume Next
        test= pvitem.ShowDetail 'true for all despite not visible

        If test= True Then    'If True for one means not fully consolidated
            ok = False
            Exit For
        End If
     Next pvitem
     End With

     If ok Then
         Set pivotRowField = pvt.RowFields(i)
     End If
     Next i
End Function
```